# how to map two tables in single hbm file

Tags: hibernate

I am new to learning hibernate.I want to map two table columns in single hibernate mapping file.

I have two tables **sample** and **Example.**

My **sample** table have 3 columns like

```
 ->upc
 ->product name
 ->product url
```

and my Example table have 2 columns

```
 -> price
 -> product name
```

I tried this way but it is not working.Please help me to solve my problem.

Thank you.

```
<class name="Trail" table="sample">

      <id name="upc" type="long">
        <column name="upc" />
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="ProductName" type="string">
        <column name="product name"  not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <property name="Producturl" type="string">
        <column name="producturl"  not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <join table="Example">
    <key column="productname"></key>
    <property name="price" type="double" >
        <column name="price"/>
    </property>
     </join>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should reference `Example` from `Sample` like:

```
<many-to-one name="example" class="mypkg.Example" fetch="select" property-ref="productName">
      <column name="product_name" unique="true" />
</many-to-one>
```

Assuming you have this in the `Example` hbm:

```
<property name="productName" type="string">
     <column name="product_name"  not-null="true" />
</property>
```